Might a graphical TeX finder help anyone?
I came across Detexify, a graphical tool for finding the Tex symbol you need, and I wanted to share. Just draw what you're looking for...

This is also available as an Android App which has probably better usability...

Hey, that's pretty useful. Shame that there is no explanation of the symbols though, not all packages are supported and don't try and find cdot: $\cdot$, $\Smiley$.

Yeh, best I can manage is a $ \smile $

I proposed a community ad for it. A few other sites with MathJax already have the same ad.
